# Tag Manager / Analytics not seeing custom dimension?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'd like to use GTM to track MemberID & MemberType in Google Analytics (universal analytics).  Is there a way to view custom dimensions in realtime?  Using the GTM debugger I believe that the dataLayer is pushing my information correctly:

[image]

But nothing shows up when looking under a custom dimension in Analytics:

[image]

I have the correct UID set inside GTM (analytics is working), I have other click events showing up in analytics reports & realtime.  This is my setup in GTM - I'm not sure what else I might be missing:

[image]

My Macros:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one way to display custom dimensions in the realtime view. However that is a hack that affects data quality, so you probably want to do this in a view created specifically for that purpose (if you want to do this at all).

This exploits the fact that custom dimension are available in the view filters. You can use this to extract the value for the custom dimension and copy it to one of the fields that are available in realtime view.

So you create a new view for debugging only. In your property settings you should have already created the custom dimensions. Now go to filters, new, custom, advanced.

For "Field A" select the name of your custom dimension. In the input field to the right enter `(.*)`. This will copy the value for the dimension to a variable.

Do not select anything for "Field B".

With "Output to Constructor" select one of the fields that is available in the realtime view (page title, source, medium, campaign, request url). Enter `$A1` in the text field. This will replace the value of the selected field with the value extracted from your custom dimension (you will lose the original value, that's why you should not do it in your live view).

Hit save. Go to realtime view and look at the data field you have just overwritten, the value for the custom dimension will show up there.

However this is of very limited usefulness - it will usually be easier and better to wait 24 hours until the data is processed and you can build a custom report with your custom dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If your pageview tag is firing on Pageview event you'll see no results in Custom Dimensions because your pageview hit is sent before the data for Custom Dimensions is ready.
You should use another hit to send this data (for example event hit) or push data to dataLayer before Pageview event.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to see Custom Dimensions in the Real-Time reports, but you can open a developer window and in the Network tab (assuming you use Chrome), you can check the hit that is being sent, and if everything is set up correctly in GTM, you should be able to see the CD's there. Just a note that data doesn't show up in standard reports until about 24 hours later